# How can I create a fuzzy fur like this? (see image)

Tags: modeling, texturing, particles, shaders, hair

Im trying to replicate this fur on this character (domo) to a model I made but I couldn't figure out how to do it with particle system or with images.I couldn't find useful tutorials on youtube so I came here.
Thank you in advance for the help

[image]

[image]

Heres my results
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you mind adding a file with the character or your initial tests?

Comment: @brockmann sure I will edit the post

Comment: @brockmann heres the renders I did

Comment: Why not try using a texture?

Comment: And on top of that you can add a  hair particle system with some brownian and a short hair lenght. Adjust the numbers and give them a light brownish grey color.

Comment: yeah I guess Ill try something like that thanks

Comment: I'd suggest have a look into the Gooseberry benchmark file: https://gooseberry.blender.org/gooseberry-production-benchmark-file/ to get an idea how they achieved that quality.

Comment: @brockmann thanks I will check it out :)

Comment: No problem, I'll try it as well and let you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable *Interpolated Children* and use a *Kink* type of *Curl* with a small distance for the *Amplitude*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks! have you changed anything else? @Allen Simpson

Comment: Wow, that's a really convincing result :).

Comment: I think around 50000 hairs, and Advanced -> Rotation -> Phase and phase randomization, but I'm not sure if that even affects hair with kink. @Axi